# Highlight any cell in a column that is the same as a single cell in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a list of dates in `column C`.

I have a single date in cell `J1`.

I want to conditional highlight all the cells in `column C` that have the same value as cell `J1`. I also want the opposite: to highlight cell `J1` if its value is found anywhere in `column C`; that way all of the duplicates will be highlighted at the same time.

I have tried with `=MATCH(C:C,$J1,0)>0`, `=COUNTIF(C:C,$J1)>1`, `=C:C=$J1`, and tons of others, but none seems to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom Formula:

```
=C1=$J$1
```

Apply to:

```
C:C
```

---

Custom Formula:

```
=MATCH(J1,C:C,0)
```

Apply to:

```
J1
```